# Form behavior when form creation data changes

Tags: forms

I've a form which shown from values in the database.

Now next day user fills it in and submits it. But the underlying data has already changed in the database.

I can see that in the validation handler form_state contains data from the form prepared after it is submitted but which contains updated values from other users, while the data submitted by the user is based on 1 day old data and he/she is not aware of changed data.

How does Drupal form behave in the scenario?

For example:

1. I load a form and I see one row of data

   Another user comes and adds a new row of data

   I submit 1 row of data I see after checking on the checkbox

   FAPI now rebuilds the form but it now finds two rows instead of one

   In validation handler it sees two rows of data(but I submitted seeing single row)

→ Assume each row is 1 checkbox + textfield

Now I want to give error and ask the user to reload the form and submit again

Answer (score 0):

If you include a function `myform_validate`, you can test the value in the $formstate array against a query for the current value in the database.  IF they do not match, return false and the original form will be redisplayed. This is explained in greater detail in the [documentation for the form api](http://drupal.org/node/37775)

Comment: No, $form and $form_state both contain latest values from database.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question. Please edit your question to express a question.